# Examples of color in mathematical papers

Tags: reference-request, big-list, research

A resource request. **Do you have any good examples of color used in a mathematical research paper?**

One example I've seen is here, in reference to tensor categories: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.02762.pdf

EDIT: Another example from the same author: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.02124.pdf

Other examples are of knot tricolorability and graph colorability (I'm sure there are loads).

To be specific, I'm asking for papers where you think the colors were *useful*: either *added something meaningful* to the paper, or else simply *made it easier to follow*.

(Most of these will probably be recent papers, since my impression is old-fashioned journals were generally black-and-white)

PS: This question is inspired by the following (closed) question: [Resources for using color in mathematical exposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838087/resources-for-using-color-in-mathematical-exposition)

Comment: (By the way, I have a personal gripe with knot tricolorability, as I've usually seen it in papers. They always use red, green, and blue! This is terrible! Red-green colorblindness is the most common form of colorblindness! Use a better palette like black, blue, and orange, or combine it with a redundant information like the shading here: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DqD5q4OWwAoqtVY.png)

Comment: Just be careful - one in twelve men and one in 200 women have some degree of colorblindness.

Comment: (Sorry, posted my comment before I saw yours.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed. I think once we have some examples, we can then talk about best practices (hopefully, without the question getting closed for being off-topic or unfocused)

Comment: I guess the proof of the four-color theorem isn't what the OP is thinking about.... ;)

Comment: @GregMartin Hah! Y'know, I just took a look at the original paper, and what do you know, turns out they don't use _any_ color! The closest I can find is [this hatching scheme](https://i.imgur.com/Uh92kpj.jpg), which as far as I can tell is only used once and never revisited.

Comment: Which I suppose adds to what I was saying about how you'd only find this in recent papers: old papers, even ones that _were about color,_ couldn't use it, because of technical limitations… and never mind any that would want to use color just to help the reader (highlighting a specific term within an equation, say).

Comment: You might want to peruse [Soergel Calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0865) by Elias and Williamson for some interesting use of colour. Each different colour is meant to correspond to a different generator of a Coxeter system $(W, S)$.